# Общение между docker-container внутри php-приложений

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

Есть веб-сервисы внутри докер-контейнеров, назовем их **api1** и **api2**.

Внутри **api1** определены следующие маршруты:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

$router->group(['prefix' => '/v1/user'], function ($router) {
    $router->post('/auth', 'Api\SignInController@auth');
    $router->post('/request-password-reset', 'Api\SignInController@request_password_reset');
    $router->post('/set-password', 'Api\SignInController@set_password');
    $router->post('/set-password/by-token', 'Api\SignInController@set_password_by_token');
});


$router->group(['prefix' => '/v1/session'], function ($router) {
    $router->post('/check-session', 'Api\SessionController@checkSession');
    $router->post('/expire', 'Api\SessionController@expire');
});
```

Из системы http-запросы он принимает исправно. А вот когда возникла необходимость из одного сервиса обращаться в другой (использую *guzzle*) возникли проблемa:

curl запрос не находит адрес контейнера, который доступен извне, при этом, если запрос идет на имя контейнера - он доходит, но возвращает какой-то бред.

Итак, мой *docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: "3.0"

services:

app-api-signin:
   container_name: app-api-signin
   build: docker/common/php
   working_dir: /app
   volumes:
     - ./api_signin:/app
   expose:
     - 9000
   links:
     - mysql
     - memcached

 nginx-api-signin:
   container_name: nginx-api-signin
   image: nginx:latest
   ports:
     - "127.0.0.2:8081:80"
   volumes:
     - ./api_signin:/app
     - ./docker/common/api-signin/nginx/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/vhost.conf
   links:
     - app-api-signin

app-api-cabinet:
   container_name: app-api-cabinet
   build: docker/common/php
   working_dir: /app
   volumes:
     - ./api_cabinet:/app
   expose:
     - 9000
   links:
     - mysql
     - memcached
     - nginx-api-signin

nginx-api-cabinet:
   container_name: nginx-api-cabinet
   image: nginx:latest
   ports:
     - "127.0.0.2:8083:80"
   volumes:
     - ./api_cabinet:/app
     - ./docker/common/api-cabinet/nginx/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/vhost.conf
   links:
     - app-api-cabinet

 mysql:
   container_name: mysql
   image: mysql:5.7
   ports:
     - "3306:3306"
   volumes:
     - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql:rw

 memcached:
   container_name: memcached
   image: memcached:latest
   ports:
     - "11211:11211"
```

Что я пробовал делать:

1) Слать запросы на адрес nginx:

```
$client = new Client([
   'base_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.2:8081'
]);
$g_request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', '/api/v1/session/check-session');
$response = $client->send($g_request);
dd($response->getBody());
```

Ответ:

```
ConnectException
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.2 port 8081: Connection refused
```

2) Слать запрос, используя вместо ip-адреса имя docker-container:

```
$client = new Client([
   'base_uri' => 'http://nginx-api-signin'
]);
$g_request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', '/api/v1/session/check-session');
$response = $client->send($g_request);
dd($response->getBody());
```

Ответ:

```
ClientException
Client error: `POST http://nginx-api-signin/api/v1/session/check-session` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr> (truncated...)
```

3) Слать запрос просто на докер-контейнер меняя метод запроса на get:

```
$client = new Client([
   'base_uri' => 'http://nginx-api-signin/'
]);
$g_request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', '/');
$response = $client->send($g_request);
dd($response->getBody());
```

Ответ (не является ошибкой):

```
Stream {#176
  -stream: stream resource @12
  wrapper_type: "PHP"
  stream_type: "TEMP"
  mode: "w+b"
  unread_bytes: 0
  seekable: true
  uri: "php://temp"
  options: []
  }
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
 }
```

Из этого всего видно, что доступ к docker-containerу получаю в последнем случае, но как мне обратиться к своему api, используя имя docker-container'a?

Comment: судя по всему, у вас nginx не пробрасывает запросы к приложению

Comment: @etki и что это значит и как это исправить?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Как происходит сетевое общение между контейнерами?

По умолчанию Docker использует bridge-сетку для каждого контейнера, выдающую ему адрес из внутреннего диапазона (например, 172.17.0.2) и позволяющую обращаться к ресурсам внешней сети. В случае с Docker Сompose такая сеть создается для каждой композиции контейнеров:

```
etki@kepler:/tmp > docker-compose up -d
Creating network "tmp_default" with the default driver
Creating tmp_nginx_1

etki@kepler:/tmp > docker network inspect tmp_default
[
  {
    "Name": "tmp_default",
    ...
    "Driver": "bridge",
    ...
  }
]
```

Это значит следующее:

- К каждому контейнеру можно обратиться по его айпи-адресу
- Каждый контейнер может обратиться к внешним (по отношению к машине) ресурсам, и его пакеты будут проброшены через основную сеть.
- **Обращения к 127.0.0.0/8 обрабатываются loopback-сетью, т.е. не выходят из контейнера в принципе**

Кроме того, в docker встроен DNS, которым пользуется Docker Compose. Внутри созданной сетки имена контейнеров будут резолвиться в их адреса:

```
etki@kepler:/tmp > docker exec tmp_nginx_1 getent hosts nginx
192.168.0.2     nginx
```

Таким образом, для обращения к контейнерам спеки `nginx-api-signin` действительно правильней всего указывать `nginx-api-signin` в качестве хоста, потому что такой запрос уйдет на внутренний ДНС и зарезолвится в реальные айпишники контейнеров. Nginx, в свою очередь, должен использовать `app-api-signin` и `app-api-cabinet` в качестве адресов FCGI-обработчиков.

## Что в этом случае может быть неправильно в примере?

Насколько видно, до nginx получается достучаться, однако он отдает 404 и 405. Это означает просто то, что nginx неправильно сконфигурирован и не воспринимает приходящие запросы как приходящие на нужный сервер; скорее всего, у него внутри нет хоста nginx-api-signin, а default_server занимается обычной раздачей статики. Должно быть достаточно создать этот хост, чтобы запросы к нему начали отрабатывать корректно.

В случае каких-либо проблем можно включить дебаг-лог nginx, указав формат `debug` для error_log и изменив команду контейнера на `[nginx-debug, -g, 'daemon off;']`

Comment: Да, действительно, необходимо было в nginx прописать название контейнера как хост и все заработало. Вы - чудо)))